# Flagging a post before voting to close results in downvote?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, down-votes, low-quality-posts

I've noticed, when seeing spam posts, that when I 'flag' it before then voting to close it, it always results in a downvote, *although* the downvote doesn't actually appear on my record as a downvote.

I was wondering if this was a bug or if this is meant to happen? It seems like it could be an easy way to double downvote (flag, close and then downvote) a question, which could surely be abused and isn't ideal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The automatic downvote for spam flags is intentional, it helps to quickly bury the spam post at the bottom of the answer list, or hide it from the frontpage.

Of course this would be theoretically abuseable, but the downvote is reversed if the spam flag is dismissed, which severely limits the extent to which you could abuse this feature. And if you make a habit of tactically using spam flags, you'll almost certainly draw the attention of the moderators and SE staff.